# Typing & in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I am trying to use the `&` symbol in LaTeX.  I have looked at many LaTeX resourses and all of them suggest using `\&` to solve the problem.  However, when I try to use this, I still get the error "Misplaced alignment tab character &."  Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: You didn't change all the `&` to `\&`

Comment: This happens to me all the time -- usually I forget one "&" somewhere, especially after importing text from elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, but please _always_ include a complete small document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For this question, a "complete small document" was unnecessary since I was asking a general question.  Since I will be using "complete small documents" in the future, how do I make them?

Comment: See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for a description of how to make an MWE and what should (not) be included.

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at [When writing a comment, how do I ensure that the person it is addressed to gets notified?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets) I suspect you didn't get a response to your question about MWEs until just now because nobody was notified of your comment.